# Modify data in a XML file with Ansible Playbook is not working

Tags: xml, xpath, automation, ansible, yaml

I have an XML file where I need to modify the real username and password instead of default. I have tried to write a small and simple playbook script to do the job. But instead of replacing the default password, it added a new line at the end of the file. Here are my XML file and playbook for your kind attention.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<Resources cacheMaxSize="100000" />
<Resource name="DataSource" 
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbNa?ssl=true&amp;sslmode=prefer&amp;protocolVersion=3"
        username="${database.user}"
        password="${database.password}"
        description="crmEpDataSource"
        initialSize="1"
        maxActive="30"
        maxIdle="10"
        minIdle="1"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="10000"
        testOnBorrow="true"
        validationQuery="select 1"
        validationInterval="5000"/>
 </Context>
```

The playbook looks like this

```
---
- name: Creating/modifying file and start the application
hosts: all
become: true

tasks:
- name: Change username on xml file
  lineinfile:
    path: "/opt/ansible/context.xml"
    regexp: 'username="${database.user}"'
    line: 'username="tamim"'
    state: present
    backup: yes
```

actually i want replace "${database.user}" with "tamim". Kindly suggest.

Comment: I think the `regexp` is not matching. Is it all you have in the `context.xml`?

Comment: @seshadri_c do you think lininfile module will work in xml file? or i need xml module for this? but i dont know how to work with xml module!! my task is ro replace the user name in this xml file...which has 3 similar part (i have put only only part here) Ply help

Comment: If there are multiple sections of XML with `username` then `lineinfile` won't work. It will work if only 1 occurrence is there.

Comment: @seshadri_c i have tried this and worked BUT only one part....  tasks: - name: Change username on context.xml file xml: path: "/opt/ansible/context.xml" xpath: /Context/Resource[1] attribute: username value: "tamim" attribute: password value: "123456789" it works but only for one child (Resource[1])...how can i use it for child 2 and 3

Comment: Then you have to use the [xml module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/xml_module.html). See the examples for an idea.

Answer (score 0):

The `lineinfile` module is probably not enough in that case. As suggested by [seshadri-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65178028/modify-data-in-a-xml-file-with-ansible-playbook-is-not-working#comment115231699_65178028), I would try something like that:

```yaml
---
tasks:
- name: Change username on xml file
  xml:
    path: "/opt/ansible/context.xml"
    xpath: //Resource
    attribute: username
    value: "tamim"
    state: present
```

Note that your XLM file is not well formed, it was missing a root node and the opening `<Context>` tag. I modified it this way to make it work:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
  <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml
  </WatchedResource>
  <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml
  </WatchedResource>
    <Resources cacheMaxSize="100000" />
    <Resource name="DataSource"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
            url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbNa?ssl=true&amp;sslmode=prefer&amp;protocolVersion=3"
            username="${database.user}"
            password="${database.password}"
            description="crmEpDataSource"
            initialSize="1"
            maxActive="30"
            maxIdle="10"
            minIdle="1"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="10000"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            validationQuery="select 1"
            validationInterval="5000"/>
 </Context>
```